# Pmos or Nmos? Which has the biggest contribution to flicker noise?

Tags: mosfet, noise, low-noise-amplifier

I would like to ask if this sentence below is correct.I had find it, when I was reading a paper.

"PMOS transistors have lower flicker noise than similarly-sized nMOS transistors in most CMOS processes."

I am a little confused why PMOS transistors have lower flicker noise.I didn't find a good explanation for this.

Comment: As flicker noise is directly related to the underlying chemistry /topology of the device and different devices are different chemistries /topologies?  Google "flicker noise" - there's a page...

Comment: I think PFET channels are deeper in the substrate than are NFETS. Thus surface traps, releasing and refilling the tiny charge buckets, affect NFETS more.

Comment: thank you  analogsystemsrf!!This sentence refer to MOSFET. I know that this question is little difficult for someone to answer, but  I think is very important for someone to understand the reason.

Comment: PFET and NFET in @analogsystemsrf's comment refer to p-channel and n-channel MOSFETs.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf *I think PFET channels are deeper in the substrate than are NFETS.* I doubt that, both NMOS and PMOS are very much surface devices. A more likely cause for the difference in noise between N- and P-type MOS becomes clear when you look at the formulas describing 1/f noise: the K-parameter is in there. K is directly related to electron/hole mobility and higher for NMOS (electron mobility) than for PMOS (hole mobility) resulting in higher K for the NMOS resulting in higer noise for the NMOS.

Comment: Very good explanation analogsystemsrf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the mean time between collisions and this is based on mobility.  Whichever device has a higher mobility, \$\mu\$, will have higher collisions because you have a greater probability of have a collision.  This *generally* means that nFETs have higher collisions and therefore higher flicker noise, but on undoped channels, you will see similar mobilities.  I have 10nm fins on my bench that show higher \$\mu_p\$.

Due to Brownian motion, you have movement whenever you have heat, and skipping a bunch of physics, you end up with the average net velocity for drift to be \$v_{dn}= -\mu_nE\$ and \$v_{dp}= \mu_pE\$ respectively. The mobility \$\mu_x\$ has the "mean free time between collisions" term of \$\tau_c\$, as \$\mu_{n,p}=\frac{q\tau_c}{2m_{n,p}}\$.

Once you calculate \$\tau_c\$, what this tells you is that for a field, \$E\$, for similar devices you will have more collisions just due to higher mobility.  To actually calculate \$\tau_c\$, you will need to pull out a device physics book and look at the density of states at a temperature under field conditions.  This is one of those things that we just empirically measure.  The math says it's proportional to \$T^{\frac{1}{2}}\$, but on the bench you see \$T^{\frac{3}{2}}\$ as your channel changes.